# dired-listing-switches -- time-style format (with a space)

Tags: dired

My version of `ls` supports a `time-style` format (with a space) as follows:

```
--time-style=+%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S
```

The entire `dired-listing-switches` looks like this:

```
"-alh --group-directories-first --time-style=+%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"
```

The space between the date and the time breaks the functionality.  Any ideas on how to use `(setq dired-listing-switches . . .)` *with a space between the date and time* would be appreciated.

I've tried single quotes and I've tried `\"` but that format is rejected.

---

**EDIT** (October 28, 2014)

I've tried single quotes:

```
--time-style='+%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'
'--time-style=+%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

I've tried escaped double quotes:

```
--time-style=\"+%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S\"

\"--time-style=+%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S\"
```

Based on Drew's suggestion below, I tried an escaped space:

```
--time-style=+%m-%d-%Y\ %H:%M:%S
```

The following link is the thread for the new Emacs bug report that I filed today:

http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18875

---

**EDIT** October 29, 2014:  For clarification purposes, the proposed `dired-listing-switches` string will either generate an error, or it will omit `hours:minutes:seconds`.  Although dired-mode does not support a list for `switches` when using `dired-insert-directory`, it is interesting to note that `insert-directory` from `files.el` permits a list format which works.  The following screen shot was generated with `insert-directory` using a `list` format for the `switches` argument.  I have already updated the bug report to mention the following expression (which bypasses dired-mode altogether).

```
(insert-directory "/" '("--dired" "-alth" "--time-style=+%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S") nil t)
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Did you try backslash-escaping the `SPC` char?  Try one or more backslashes ;-). If you do not find a reasonable workaround or a good answer here, consider filing an Emacs bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. (Why did you try backslashing a *double-quote* char?)

Comment: @Drew -- I found a hack, but not a good solution.  The function `indirect-directory` in `files.el` supports switches in the form of either a string or a list.  The function `dired-indirect-directory` within `dired.el` expects only a string, as is reflected by the line of code:  `(setq switches (concat "--dired " switches))`  Replacing that line of code with `(setq switches '("--dired" "-alh" "--group-directories-first" "--time-style=+%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")))` permits a proper display of a dired-mode buffer with a space between the date and time.  I'll file a bug report when I have some free time.

Comment: @Drew -- It is possible that either or both of the above-mentioned functions need to be modified to better support both strings and lists for switches.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. File the bug report, and Emacs Dev will work with you to find out what the best approach might be. Thanks for finding this and working on it.

Comment: Just a note to fix erroneous references to function names mentioned in my previous comment -- I should have written `insert-directory` from `files.el` and `dired-insert-directory` from `dired.el`.  [I had erroneously used the word `indirect` instead of `insert`.]  It is possible to use a `list` instead of a `string` for the `switches` with `insert-directory` from `files.el` -- the expression to be evaluated (which works) looks like:  `(insert-directory "/" '("--dired" "-alth" "--time-style=+%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S") nil t)`.  However, that won't work as a string using `dired-insert-directory`.

Comment: Oh hi @lawlist! Welcome to Emacs.SE :)

Comment: You should accept York's answer, which is easy, it works, and doesn't require trying to use other characters in place of spaces.

Answer (score 3):

I succeeded to use a Unicode char U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE to split the time style:

```
(setq dired-listing-switches (purecopy (concat "-AhFlv --group-directories-first --time-style=+%d/%m/%y" (string ?\u2008) "%R")))
```

Although I don't know whether it has any implication on `dired`. Note, that you **must** also add this:

```
(setq directory-listing-before-filename-regexp
      (purecopy (concat "\\([0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] \\)\\|"
                        directory-listing-before-filename-regexp)))
```

to prevent a “No file on this line” error.

Tested with 24.5.1 and 25.0.50.1 on Arch Linux.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you also achieve seconds using your method?  `"--time-style=+%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"`  Your example looks very similar to the generic default.

Comment: Yes, why not. Replace `%R` with `%H:%M:%S` and `[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]` with `[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]\\([.,][0-9]+\\)?`This is not like a generic default: The space before `%R` is **not** a regular space, so `split-string`, that works on `ls` switches doesn't split by it

Comment: Sounds promising -- I'll test it out in the next day or so, as I am presently working on another project -- thank you for the proposed solution -- I look forwarding to trying it out.

Comment: I actually tried right now my solution with an addition of seconds, before posting it :)

Comment: Does it also work with U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE? That might work better with setups that don't use Unicode throughout.

Comment: Seems to work with NO-BREAK space. Just replace the space character before `%R`. What I don't like though, is that DejaVu Sans Mono, the font I use as default, represents this character as underline ('_'), when this same font represents PUNCTUATION SPACE as space (' ')

Comment: On the master branch of Emacs (aka trunk), I get:  `(error ("Listing directory failed but ‘access-file’ worked"))`.  Based on the comments above, it appears that this answer proposes to substitute spaces with certain Unicode characters within the `dired` buffer.  This is not an ideal solution in my opinion, but is perhaps a viable workaround for some people.  I have a working custom version of `dired-mode` that accepts a *list* for directory switches, whereas the stock version of `dired-mode` uses a *string* -- however, I would need to spend time backtracking to see how I achieved the result.

Comment: I compiled 25.0.50.1 especially to check this. 1. It works, see the screenshot 2. Please try the updated instructions, where the space char is given explicitly by its codepoint. Perhaps, you put a regular space. 3. The formatting is done for `ls` and not specifically for `dired`. The purpose of `directory-listing-before-filename-regexp` is to parse whatever some people define in the switches. 4. You may wish to submit a patch for `dired`, rather than using a local copy, as upstream its code may be changed significantly. 5. Enjoy whatever solution you find useful :)

Comment: In addition, please try the switches on the `ls` itself, ensuring you don't use an alias. For ex., `/usr/bin/ls -Ah...` Perhaps, you have a version not supporting some of the switches. And if it doesn't help, please, post here the name of the dir you try to list. Has it spaces or some unusaual chars in its name? Although it works here with spaces

Comment: `insert-directory` has changed since October 2014 -- i.e., `(insert-directory "/" '("--dired" "-alth" "--time-style=+%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S") nil t)` no longer works on Emacs Trunk (master branch) build from September 11, 2015.  This is one of the main reasons that I have slowly/steadily been separating everything that I normally use on a daily basis from the rest of Emacs, so that future revisions do not break something that I rely upon for my daily workflow.  Since `dired-mode` uses `insert-directory` in `files.el`, the latter is part of the reasons why your proposed answer doesn't work on OSX.

Comment: I cannot check this on OSX. However, on Linux it works. I cannot check the code of trunk right now, but when I talked about `split-string` I meant the code at line 6323 in `files.el` in the `insert-directory` of 24.5.1. The split is done on the switches by whitespace chars, without checking whether they are quoted/escaped. And as such, `ls` gets the time style with a space in between, hence, it cannot process it, as its switches must be quoted, if they include space, e.g on cmd you write `ls -l --time-style "+%d %M"`

Comment: Sorry, lawlist, I don't get it. Not only `insert-directory` did **not** changed between 24.5 and 25 (although there are changes in `files.el`), but the very same command, you gave in your previous comment, [works for me](http://i.imgur.com/saV99Rm.png)

Comment: @lawlist See York's answer below, which avoids all of this.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
(setq dired-listing-switches "-alh --group-directories-first --time-style \"+%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S\"")
```

The key is replacing `--time-style=xxxx` with `--time-style xxxx` which doesn't confuse the function `split-string-and-unquote`.

Comment: Thank you! This is so much better than everything else posted on this page, and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This doesn't work however with Tramp, e.g. `C-x d /sudo::/etc`, for Emacs 28.2 the buffer is empty. `\"--time-style=XXX\"` shows files, but throws away your time style. I started using `TIME_STYLE`  env. var. and `(with-eval-after-load 'tramp
  (push (concat "TIME_STYLE=" (getenv "TIME_STYLE")) tramp-remote-process-environment))`. Need probably to do it for local (`sudo`) connections only